# How can I check that a file is a valid HDF5 file?

Tags: c++, validation, hdf5, hdf

Based on the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344648/c-c-hdf5-read-string-attribute/31351401#31351401), I have a file image loaded into memory as a string with a valid handler. This was done using `H5LTopen_file_image()`.

How can I check that a file is a valid HDF5 file?

I found only a program called [`H5check`](https://support.hdfgroup.org/products/hdf5_tools/h5check.html), which has a complicated source code. So, I'm wondering, is there a simple function with a simple return value to verify that whatever in the `hid_t` handler is a valid HDF5 file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++:

```
    std::string filename = "foo.h5";
    if(!H5::H5File::isHdf5(filename.c_str()))
    {
        std::string err_msg = filename + " is not an HDF5 file.\n";
        throw std::logic_error(err_msg);
    }
```

In Python, use

```
import h5py
if not h5py.is_hdf5('foo.h5'):
    raise ValueError('Not an hdf5 file')
```